# Can OpenRasta run alongside an existing Web App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openrasta

Is there a preferred way to configure an ASP.net solution so that OpenRasta can run alongside an existing application asp.net application.

I'm interested in what the process would be for a request coming in to the server for:

- a resource OR knew about
- a resource the old web app knew about
- a resource neither app know how to handle

Ideally I'd like to keep the 2 projects separated so that we can gradually move over functionality to being based on OpenRasta and away from our legacy app.

---

As an example, on a machine with a virtual directory of /api

- Requests to /api/contacts <-- handled by OpenRasta.
- Requests to /api/v0.1/contacts <-- handled by Legacy web app.
- Requests to /api/junk <-- handled by Neither web app.

---

Answer (score 1):

OR will try and match the incoming URI to its uri tables. If it doesn't find any matching routes, it lets the request go down the asp.net pipeline.

So short **answer is yes**, you can simply keep your aspx / ihttphandler / asp.net routing in place, and add new routes to openrasta.